# Do Multi-Signature Wallets Require Two Separate Bitcoin Wallets?

Tags: multi-signature

Put more simply, is it possible to set up a multi-signature wallet that takes both signatures from itself?

Comment: // , On another note, are Married Wallets an example of this?

Answer (score 4):

No, two wallets are not required. It sounds like you might be confusing wallets with addresses, where one bitcoin wallet can house many bitcoin addresses and keys.

If you want to be able to execute a 2 of 3 multisig from one wallet you can do so with [bitcoin core](https://bitcoin.org/en/download) with raw transactions. You will have to keep track of the private keys and [redeemscript](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Pay_to_script_hash) yourself and save them somewhere like a thumb drive for example.

Here's a [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YN2Vyu9RupU) that can guide you through creating and spending with your multisig address using bitcoin core.

Comment: Exactly the kind of response I was looking for. I am aware that wallets can have multiple addresses, and, with the HD Wallet standard, even "sub-wallets". Could one set up such a 2 of 3 multisig where all 3 signatures would come from addresses from the same wallet?

Comment: Absolutely, you can do that with bitcoin core. Create 3 addresses within your bitcoin core wallet and then use those 3 public keys to create the multisig address. Then you would have all 3 keys coming from the same wallet. You still have to sign each transaction twice with a raw transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Shamir's secret sharing, in this case you are not technically implementing multisignature.  This methodology can be used to divide the private key S of one address into n pieces.  Using this method m of n sections of the secret can be used to derive the secret key.  This may be used as a comparable solution to multisig when only 1 address is used (this method obviously only requires one wallet)

Answer (score 0):

No. Technically, you don't need two separated wallets.

But as far as i know there is no wallet app that supports your case. Maybe because your use-case doesn't sounds after a reasonable usage of multisig.

The main purpose of using multisig is to get multiple signatures from a) multiple devices (=multiple keystores/wallets) or b) multiple identities (=every identity keeps it's own wallet).

Comment: // , Believe me, there's a use case for it.